# Error "found unreadable content" when open excel file written by .to_excel()

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I'm practicing web scraping, and try to get some info of cars.
I want one of my dataframe columns be a **hyperlink** to the model image, and I succeeded in creating the formula and saving it to dataframe

For example:

```
print(suvs['images'][0])
=HYPERLINK("https://www.cstatic-images.com/car-pictures/main/USD00AUS052A021001.png"; "Audi Q3")

print(suvs['images'][3])
=HYPERLINK("https://www.cstatic-images.com/car-pictures/main/USD00AUS011B021001.png"; "Audi Q7")
```

, but when opening the file (I'm using Excel 2010), it throws me that error "Excel found unreadable content...", and if I responded with Yes, it deletes the column contents.

Here is log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error040320_03.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'D:\Users\Tamer\PycharmProjects\Udemy\suvs.xlsx'</summary><removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

I tried to copy and paste the link generated by the code into the file, and it works very well.
So what is the problem?

Thank you

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
    HEADERS = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
    URL = 'https://www.cars.com/research/audi/'

    images = []
    models = []
    model_years = []
    msrp_ranges = []
    consumer_ratings = []
    combined_mpgs = []
    body_styles = []

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    data = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    cards = data.find_all('div', class_='card make-model-card suvs')

    for card in cards:
        model = card.p.text
        models.append(model)

        image = card.img['data-image-src']
        # Creating hyperlinks to save it in suvs.xlsx file
        hyperlink = f'=HYPERLINK("{image}"; "{model}")'
        print(hyperlink)
        images.append(hyperlink)
        # images.append(image)

        # Get 'More Details' page URL
        details_url = 'https://www.cars.com' + card.div.a.attrs['href']
        details_page = requests.get(details_url, headers=HEADERS)
        details_data = BeautifulSoup(details_page.text, 'html.parser')
        details = details_data.find_all('div', class_='expanded-list-contents')

        model_year = details_data.h3.text
        model_years.append(model_year)

        if details_data.find('li', class_='expanded-list-item'):
            msrp_range = details_data.find('li', class_='expanded-list-item').text.replace('MSRP Range\n', '').strip()
        else:
            msrp_range = ''

        if details_data.find('td', class_='expanded-list-item'):
            msrp_range = details_data.find('li', class_='expanded-list-item').text.replace('MSRP Range\n', '').strip()
        else:
            msrp_range = ''

        msrp_ranges.append(msrp_range)

        if details_data.find('div', class_='star-rating__consumer-review'):
            consumer_rating = details_data.find('div', class_='star-rating__consumer-review').text.replace('\n', '').strip()
            consumer_rating = consumer_rating[:5] + ' ' + consumer_rating[-15:]
        else:
            consumer_rating = 'Not rated yet'

        consumer_ratings.append(consumer_rating)

    # Creating dataframe "homes"
    suvs = pd.DataFrame({
        'images': images,
        'models': models,
        'year': model_years,
        'msrp_ranges': msrp_ranges,
        'consumer_ratings': consumer_ratings,
        #     'combined_mpgs': combined_mpgs,
        #     'body_styles': body_styles
    })

    file_name = 'suvs.xlsx'
    suvs.to_excel(file_name, index=False)  # index=False to avoid creating index column

    # to see where you're missing data and how much data is missing
    print(suvs.isnull().sum())

except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print("Couldn't connect to the requested page!\n"
          'Please, check your internet connection.')

except PermissionError:
    print(f'The {file_name} file is opened.\n'
          'Please, close it, and run the script again.')
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a comma instead of a semicolon in the formula?

Comment: Hi Rory,
Thanks for replying.

Hooray, I tried now, and it works.

You made my day :)
Thanks Rory

Comment: Hi Rory,

Do you know how to make the hyperlink been displayed formatted in excel file when I open it? I mean without formatting it inside Excel.
Because it's displayed as ordinary text (Although it works)

Thanks again :)

Comment: In Excel,  you'd set the cell style to "Hyperlink". I don't know how you do that in whatever language that is though!